# Is there a way to merge two tables with overwriting and multiplying results using a single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables, the first one stores continents, the second one stores the animals with default presence and the third one stores the exceptions from the second table for particular continents and animals.

continents (limit to 3 to simplify results)

```
| continent_code |
|----------------|
| EU             |
| OC             |
| AN             |
```

animals_default_presence

```
| animal_id | animal     | presence |
|-----------|------------|----------|
| 1         | dog        | 1        |
| 2         | kangaroo   | 0        |
| 3         | polar bear | 0        |
```

continent_animals_presence_exceptions

```
| continent_code | animal_id | presence |
|----------------|-----------|----------|
| OC             | 2         | 1        |
| AN             | 1         | 0        |
| AN             | 3         | 1        |
```

The result is a summary of all continents and animals which live there:

```
| continent_code | animal_id |
|----------------|-----------|
| EU             | 1         |
| OC             | 1         |
| OC             | 2         |
| AN             | 3         |
```

Can I get such results with a single MySQL query?

Comment: yes you can. You need some JOINs and probably a CASE statement (to deal with the two presence fields). Have you tried anything at all? P.S. If you make us something like a [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with your tables and sample data already present (you can just copy your CREATE TABLE and generate some INSERT statements from your MySQL server), it'll make it a lot easier for people to try out queries and thus be able to help you. Thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`.  I think the following is all that you need:

```
select c.continent_code, adp.animal_id
from continent c cross join
     animals_default_presence adp 
where adp.presence = 1 and
      (c.continent_code, adp.animal_id) not in 
            (select cape.continent_code, cape.animal_id
             from continent_animals_presence_exceptions cape
             where cape.presence = 0
            )
union all
select cape.continent_code, cape.animal_id
from continent_animals_presence_exceptions cape
where cape.presence = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f5b36e9d3e4125435958691ee8065e6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to do a `CROSS JOIN` between animals and continents to get all possible combinations of them. Now, you can do `LEFT JOIN` to exceptions table based on the animal and continent.

Eventually, a little complex `WHERE` condition can be used to filter out the required result-set. We either consider those rows where default presence is 1, and there is no exception for them, OR, those rows where default presence is 0, but there is an exception defined for them.

```
SELECT c.continent_code,
       cape.animal_id
FROM   (SELECT c.continent_code,
               a.animal_id,
               a.presence AS default_presence
        FROM   animals_default_presence AS a
               CROSS JOIN continents AS c
              ) AS all_combos
       LEFT JOIN continent_animals_presence_exceptions AS cape
              ON cape.continent_code = default_present_combos.continent_code
                 AND cape.animal_id = default_present_combos.animal_id
WHERE  ( all_combos.default_presence = 1
         AND ( cape.presence = 1
                OR cape.presence IS NULL ) )
        OR ( all_combos.default_presence = 0
             AND cape.presence = 1 )
```

---

**Previous version using `UNION ALL`:**

One way is to utilize `UNION ALL`. In one of the `SELECT` queries, you can get all the combinations of animal and continent_code where the default presence of animal is **1**. However, we will need to do "anti-join" using `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL` to eliminate exceptions where the "presence" of the default animal is defined as **0** on a particular continent.

In another `SELECT` query, we simply get combinations for the animals whose default presence is **0**, but their presence is **1** on some of the continents, as defined in the exceptions.

```
SELECT 
  c.continent_code, cape.animal_id 
FROM 
  (SELECT c.continent_code, a.animal_id 
   FROM animals_default_presence AS a 
   CROSS JOIN continents AS c 
   WHERE a.presence = 1) AS default_present_combos 
   LEFT JOIN continent_animals_presence_exceptions AS cape 
          ON cape.continent_code = default_present_combos.continent_code 
             AND cape.animal_id = default_present_combos.animal_id 
             AND cape.presence = 0 
WHERE cape.animal_id IS NULL

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
  cape.continent_code, cape.animal_id 
FROM animals_default_presence AS a 
JOIN continent_animals_presence_exceptions AS cape 
  ON cape.animal_id = a.animal_id 
     AND cape.presence = 1 
WHERE a.presence = 0
```